# Destination array was not long anough when reading mp3 file with NAudio

Tags: naudio

I've got this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(@"C:\testAudio.mp3");
        long count = reader.Length;
        if (count <= int.MaxValue)
        {
             byte[] info = new byte[count];
             reader.Read(info, 0, (int)count);
             Console.WriteLine("Succesfull read");
        }
        else
             Console.WriteLine("Could not read");
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(ex);
     }
}
```

that prints out the following exception message:

```
System.ArgumentException: Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds. 
at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length, Boolean reliable) 
at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length) 
at NAudio.Wave.AcmMp3FrameDecompressor.DecompressFrame(Mp3Frame frame, Byte[] dest, Int32 destOffset) in C:\NAudio-Source\NAudio\FileFormats\Mp3\Mp3FrameDecompressor.cs:line 50 
at NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader.Read(Byte[] sampleBuffer, Int32 offset, Int32 numBytes) in C:\NAudio-Source\NAudio\Wave\WaveStreams\Mp3FileReader.cs:line 338 
at Tester.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Tester\Program.cs:line 30
```

I've downloaded NAudio code and I've been debugging it but I can't find the cause of the error, although, as you can see on the stack trace is in *NAudio-Source\NAudio\FileFormats\Mp3\Mp3FrameDecompressor.cs:line 50*

Am I doing something wrong? By the way, it only happens with a few mp3 files, others are read just fine. I could send one conflicted file if needed.

-------------------------EDIT TO REFER TO THREAD ON NAUDIO CODEPLEX--------------------------------

See this issue on Codeplex [Same question on Codeplex NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/workitem/16345)

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to read the entire file in one hit. Instead, read around one seconds worth at a time and keep going until Read returns 0.

Comment: Hi Mark, you already answer this question on the [Codeplex thread] (http://naudio.codeplex.com/workitem/16345). The problem is that NAudio does not handles correctly frames a different sample rate, it throws the exception above because of the buffer lenght. Actually reading the file in smaller chunks does not correct the problem, so I won't mark this as an answer. Post a reference to the codeplex thread if you like and I'll mark that as an answer. Thanks